# Function for scanning /proc

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a function, `scan_ps()`, for scanning `/proc`, to replace a combination of `popen()` and `ps(1)`.

`scan_ps()` scans /proc, calling `filter()` on each /proc/[pid]. Entries for which filter() returns nonzero are stored in strings allocated via malloc(3), and collected in array `ps_list`. If /proc/[pid]/cmdline is empty, the entry will not be stored. And return value is the count of entries.

But I wonder that I have to add or remove some corner-case handlings for `read()`, `malloc()`, or `realloc()`.

```
int scan_ps(struct my_proc ***ptr, int (*filter)(const struct my_proc *)) {
    DIR * dirp;
    struct dirent * dp;
    int count = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    char path[MAX_LEN_STR], buf[MAX_LEN_STR];
    int fd, n;
    unsigned int size = 16;
    struct my_proc ** ps_list, ** ps_list2;
    struct my_proc * current_ps;

    dirp = opendir("/proc");
    if (NULL==dirp)
        return -1;

    ps_list = malloc(sizeof(struct my_proc *)*size);
    if (ps_list==NULL) {
        printf("%s: malloc failed(ps_list)\n",__func__);
        goto failed_closedir;
    }

    while (NULL != (dp = readdir(dirp))) {
        pid = atoi(dp->d_name);
        if (0 == pid)
            continue;
        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%u/cmdline", pid);
        fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0) {
            printf("%s: failed to open() (%d)\n",__func__, errno);
            continue;
        }
        n = read(fd, buf, MAX_LEN_STR);
        if (0 == n) {
            // cmdline is empty. maybe kernel process.
            printf("%s: pid:%u cmdline is empty!\n",__func__, pid);
            close(fd);
            continue;
        }
        n = (MAX_LEN_STR - 1) > n ? n : (MAX_LEN_STR - 1);
        buf[n] = '\0';
        close(fd);

        current_ps = malloc(sizeof(struct my_proc));
        if (current_ps==NULL) {
            printf("%s: malloc failed\n",__func__);
            goto failed_ps_list;
        }
        current_ps->pid = pid;
        strncpy_v2(current_ps->cmdline, buf, MAX_LEN_STR);
        if ( !filter(current_ps) ) {
            printf("%s: let it go. currnet_ps\n", __func__);
            free(current_ps);
            continue;
        }
        // prepare ps_list
        if (count!=0 && (count%16)==0) {
            size += 16;
            ps_list2 = realloc(ps_list, sizeof(struct my_proc *)*size);
            if (ps_list2==NULL) {
                printf("%s: malloc failed(ps_list2)\n",__func__);
                goto failed;
            }
            ps_list = ps_list2;
        }
        ps_list[count++] = current_ps;
    }
    closedir(dirp);
    *ptr = ps_list;
    return count;
failed:
    free(current_ps);
failed_ps_list:
    while(count--) {
        free(ps_list[count]);
    }
    free(ps_list);
failed_closedir:
    closedir(dirp);
    return -1;
}
```

`scan_ps()` works with below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define FALSE               (0)
#define TRUE                (!FALSE)
#define MAX_LEN_STR         256

struct my_proc {
    pid_t pid;
    char cmdline[256];
};

int true_filter(const struct my_proc * a) {
    return TRUE;
}

char *strncpy_v2(char *dest, char *src, unsigned int size){
    if (size==0) return dest;
    dest[--size] = '\0';
    return strncpy(dest, src, size);
}

int main(){
    int n;
    struct my_proc ** ps_list;
    n = scan_ps(&ps_list, true_filter);
    if (n<0) {
        printf("%s: n=%d something wrong!\n", __func__, n);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("%s: n=%d\n", __func__, n);
    while (n--) {
        printf("%s: %u, %s\n", __func__, ps_list[n]->pid, ps_list[n]->cmdline);
        free(ps_list[n]);
    }
    free(ps_list);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to show `main()`, `struct my_proc`, and etc. Now, there is no uncompleted part.

Comment: This still lacks the `#include` lines for the required header files.

Comment: I added `#include` lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder that I have to add or remove some corner-case handlings for read(), malloc(), or realloc().

```
int scan_ps(struct my_proc ***ptr, int (*filter)(const struct my_proc *));
```

**Make review easier**

Allocating to the size of the type rather than the size of an object obliges a reviewer to double check - did code use the right type?  Instead, make code easier to review, code right and maintain.

```
// ps_list = malloc(sizeof(struct my_proc *)*size);
ps_list = malloc(sizeof *ps_list * size);

// current_ps = malloc(sizeof(struct my_proc));
current_ps = malloc(sizeof *current_ps);
```

**Why use `unsigned`?**

With array sizing and indexing, `size_t` is the [Goldilocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_principle) type, neither too narrow nor too wide.

```
// unsigned int size = 16;
size_t size = 16;
```

**Questionable type**

Why use `int` when `read()` returns `ssize_t`?

```
// int n;
ssize_t n;
n = read(fd, buf, MAX_LEN_STR);
```

**Questionable code**

Why potentially shorted `n` and not report this as an error?  Just read less.

```
// n = read(fd, buf, MAX_LEN_STR);
// n = (MAX_LEN_STR - 1) > n ? n : (MAX_LEN_STR - 1);

n = read(fd, buf, MAX_LEN_STR - 1);
// or better
n = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf - 1);
```

---

**Proper use of `goto`**

`goto` is often mis-used.  This is an acceptable usage.

**Why `MAX_LEN_STR`?**

For a max path length, I'd expect [`PATH_MAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9449241/2410359)

```
// char path[MAX_LEN_STR];
char path[PATH_MAX /* maybe + 1 */];
```

**Why 256?**

Avoid naked magic numbers as in `char cmdline[256];`.  Perhaps `char cmdline[MAX_LEN_STR];`?

**Why `MAX_LEN_STR`?**

In limiting string copy, best to use the size of the destination and not some other constant.

```
// strncpy_v2(current_ps->cmdline, buf, MAX_LEN_STR);
strncpy_v2(current_ps->cmdline, buf, sizeof current_ps->cmdline);
```

**Missing error report**

`strncpy_v2()` does not indicate it failed to copy a complete string. With all the other good error checking, it is curious code does not report this.  If failure cannot occur because of the construction of code, why then have `strncpy_v2()` versus simple `strcpy()`?  Being "safe" by not over-writing memory is good, yet not reporting insufficiencies is not.

**Sign and potential print specifier mis-match**

A `pid_t` is *some* signed type.  [Ref](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/types.h.html).  Best to use signed math and cast to a wide *signed* type to print.

```
// pid = atoi(dp->d_name);
pid = atoll(dp->d_name);

// snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%u/cmdline", pid);
snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%jd/cmdline", (intmax_t) pid);
// or
snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "/proc/%lld/cmdline", (long long) pid);
```

---

Other stuff

**What is `*ptr` in failure?**

When `scan_ps()` fails, returns -1, consider setting `*ptr = NULL;`

**Lose a `*`**

Further, consider using re-architect and using a return value of `NULL` as an error indication.  Otherwise the return value is a pointer to a `NULL` terminated array.  You do lose one `*`, but I'd say that is good.

```
struct my_proc **scan_ps(int (*filter)(const struct my_proc *));
```

**Why define `FALSE, TRUE`?**

Instead, use `stdbool.h`.

```
// #define FALSE               (0)
// #define TRUE                (!FALSE)
//   return TRUE;

#include <stdbool.h>
...
   return true;
```